# Sinch call recording not working

Tags: javascript, sinch

The following code allows the call to go through, but the recording is never published to my s3 bucket (I already set up s3 access with Sinch).
Any idea why?

```
app.use('/sinch', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("GOT SINCH CALL");
  console.log(req.body.event);
  console.log(req.body.callid);

  var aceResp = {
        "action":
        {
            "name" : "connectMXP",
            "record": true
        }
      };
      res.json(aceResp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.sinch = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

if (request.body.hasOwnProperty('event')) {

if (request.body.event === 'ice') {
  response.json({
    'action':
      {
        'name': 'connectConf',
        'conferenceId': request.body.to.endpoint,
        "record" : true
      }
  })
}
else if (request.body.event === 'dice') {
  response.status(200).send('OK')
}

}
else {
  response.status(200).send('OK')
}

})
```

Hi! It is an example from my firebase functions. Not sure if it is really correct, but it works for me